# "sudo mysql" does not work, access denied

Tags: mysql, mariadb, sudo

I am used to administrating the mysql server with a password-less root user, using `sudo mysql` (or equivalently `sudo mysql -u root`). However, after installing `mariadb-server-10` on a Ubuntu 16.04 LTS installation, this fails:

```
⌂134% [@apollo:~] $ sudo mysql
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

After I used the `--skip-grant-table` workaround to set a password, `mysql -u root -p"new password"` works, but `sudo mysql` still fails.

Is a configuration change required to allow `sudo` to bypass the MySQL password prompt?

Comment: Why would anything be allowed to bypass a correct login? Use `mysql -u root -p` and enter the password at the prompt

Comment: Do you want to login to the MySQL database with the root user without a password being stored in the database or do you want a password in the database? And how is `sudo` plays a role in all this?

Comment: @RiggsFolly as having `sudo` privileged allows to stop the MySQL server and start it without grant tables, and as of that allows to bypass the correct login. So expecting that `sudo` might allow password less local login is not that strange. And iirc this is the case for postgres. But yes afaik it is not possible for mysql.

Comment: The OS `root` is totally independent of MySQL's `root`.  `sudo` does nothing. in your context.

Comment: did you see my answer?

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid using a method to skip password prompt, if it exists.

The proper way to establish a mysql connection from command line is this:

```
mysql -u myUserName -p
```

It'll prompt you to insert the password for the specified user (e.g. `myUserName`).

You can also directly specify the password after the `-p` parameter **but be aware** that doing so it's strongly discouraged because in the server's log that whole command will be saved including the password. Therefore anyone who can access that file can read your credentials.

See [the official documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/connecting.html) and the [man](https://linux.die.net/man/1/mysql) documentation for additional information.

You can also do `mysql --help` in command line to get the `man` guide.